# How to save a scene setup with a named label (multiple renders from single file)?

Tags: rendering, workflow

- I have a file with 10 objects in it
- I want to produce 5 different renders from this file
- Each render should have its own camera angle and light
- Each render may have the objects differently arranged/moved
- I should be able to switch between each render I want to produce by clicking on a name of it in a list, and cameras, lights, object placement/visibility should follow.

Is this possible to accomplish in a single file in Blender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways that come to mind.

1. Separate *Collection* for each setup. Uses the same render settings.
2. Different *Scene* for each setup. You can set up different render settings for each scene.

---

*Using Collections. One click to enable, second click to set camera as active.*

[image]

*Using Scenes. Change your setup and active camera with one click.*

[image]